# Best practice to implement paging in rest api for Get Items Endpoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, best-practices

I currently managed to do it with

`/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=${query}&$expand=${expand}&$top=${pageSize}&$skip=${top}`

I tried using `skiptoken` instead of skip but no `skiptoken` result is returned.

I tried adding `"ListItemCollectionPosition": null` to the query but no `ListItemCollectionPosition` is returned.

Comment: $skip attribute is not available on O365

Comment: Maybe it is not availiable for other endpoints. It already works for monthes for me in `GetItems`. It is tested and running in production.

Comment: $skipt does not works for listitem endpoints, it works for lists endpoint. also the skiptoken is the best way to implement paging. make sure you only have next and previous buttons, as skiptoken will provide data only for next and previous call. you will also need to add RowLimit i.e $top for REST

Comment: skiptoken wont work in `/GetItems(query=@v1)`. I try to use it but `__nextPage` is not returned for me.